# node js rapid desktop/web app development

Tags: node.js

I am looking for a node.js library which suits my use case, which is the following: I want to use node to build a multi-user realtime office automation app. The key requirement would be rapid development, at the cost of performance, because it will only have max 5 users and it will run on a LAN. So I don't want to mess around with client and server model sync, I want to program in node as if it were a traditional single-user desktop app, where you set up your windows and respond to user events - except here the 'windows' are instances of users' browsers.

In theory this should be rather easy, because using socket.io you can quickly set up code which allows the server to dynamically send javascript to be executed in the client's browser, enabling it to be entirely controlled from the server. The idea would be kinda what [meteor](http://www.meteor.com/) and [derby](http://derbyjs.com/) are aiming for, but they're still at an alpha stage and they're probably overkill for what I want to do anyway. I want something simple.

Is anyone trying to do this already? If not, I take it that there's a niche to be filled... any pointers would be helpful.

This is the kind of thing I'm looking for... it should be this easy:

```
app.get('/', gs.remote(function(client) {
    button = client.body.append('button', {
        text: "Click me!",
        click: function() {
            console.log("A user clicked a button");
        }
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [SocketStream](https://github.com/socketstream/socketstream) would be perfect for what you want to do. It references Meteor and Derby as the commercial counterparts and it is really simple to get up and running. It uses socket.io to send events to all clients (safely transported using redis or server memory if you don't want to use redis) with a clear separation between the server and the client.

As standard it tracks connected users so you can send specific events to specific users if you so wish. Additionally it uses websockets to refresh your browser and restart the server whenever you make a change in the development code. When deploying to a production environment you can optionally tell the framework to minify and package all your assets for that performance benefit (it's literally just a flag in the config file).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that.